# Are there any patterns in which syllable stress falls on?

Tags: фонетика, наголос

My books have said that Ukrainian stress is irregular. The same could be said of English, but there are still some patterns. For example: Stress always falls on the first syllable of words ending in "-tion". Are there any such patterns in Ukrainian?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are several notable patterns. **Caveat, quite often, they have their own exceptions**, so one should not solely rely on these patterns, unless being certain about stressing a specific word.

## Nouns

- *Declined* nouns often keep stress on stem (not on case endings):
  *дру́г**ом***, *дру́г**ові***, *повідо́мленн**ю***
- Nouns created with the suffixes usually keep suffix *un*stressed:
  *револю́**ція*** (here is `-tion`), *пози́**ція***, *іннова́**ція***
- *Plural* nouns, ending with `-и` — stress falls on the last syllable (also declined):
  *огірк**и́***, *огірк**і́в***, *книжк**и́***, *книж**о́к***
  but: *іме́нник**и***, *сму́жк**и***
- *Multi-stem nouns* — stress falls on the second stem:
  *довготрива́лий*, *просторі́чний*
- *Gerund-like* nouns ending with `-ання` — stress falls on the suffix:
  *кох**а́ння***, *єдн**а́ння***,  *чит**а́ння***
  but: *бі́г**ання***
- Nouns/Adjectives/Verbs with `не-` prefix do *not* get stress on this prefix:
  ***не***знайо́мець, ***не***зда́тність, ***не***доста́тній
  but: ***не́**хтувати*

## Adjectives

- Two-syllable adjectives often get stress on last syllable:
  *міцни́й*, *дурни́й*
  but: *жи́рний*
- Diminutive suffix `-еньк-` often gets stressed:
  *солод**е́ньк**ий*

## Verbs

- Suffixes of Plural 1st and 2nd Person `-емо`, `-имо`, `-ете`, `-ите` get stress on the very last syllable:
  *п'**ємо́***, *крич**ите́***
  but: *бу́д**ете***, *хо́д**ите***, *зали́ш**имо***
- Suffixes of *imperative mood* `-імо` gets stress:
  *ход**і́мо***, *залиш**і́мо***

---

## Reading

- Олександр Пономарів — [Наголос](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/hagolos)